# How can I see the average of tag's questions' score?

Tags: support, statistics

I am interested into comparing tags' value. (Like C++ and C#) Is there any tool or statistics place for that?

Comment: This is more a measure of "how willing are followers of this tag to upvote" than "tags' value" in my opinion...

Comment: @Wooble Tag's value means that on average people here prefer C++ question over C# one. You could partly describe it as "how willing are...". It's economy stuff.

Comment: The average person isn't even going to read a haskell question, but when they do, they seem to vote it up.

Comment: @Wooble 5.11 value, partly high because of it's rareness. (Same as any other rare material that is useful in a way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a SEDE query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/235748/average-score-for-tag):

```sql
select
  sum(p.Score) as TotalScore
  ,count(p.Id) as NumberOfPosts
  ,cast(sum(p.Score) as float) / cast(count(p.Id) as float) as AverageScore
from
  Posts p
  inner join PostTags pt on pt.PostId = p.Id
  inner join dbo.Tags t on t.Id = pt.TagId
where
  t.TagName = '##tag##'
```

It's worth noting that deleted posts are not in the data, so heavily downvoted (or upvoted) questions that are deleted will not influence the results.

This is the result for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
TotalScore NumberOfPosts AverageScore     
---------- ------------- ---------------- 
726771     320904        2.26476142397726
```

And for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23):

```
TotalScore NumberOfPosts AverageScore     
---------- ------------- ---------------- 
1288972    706105        1.82546788367169
```

Comment: I know nothing about SQL, just to check: are you sure it's not the sum of down votes and up votes? (That down votes count as +1 and up votes too)

Comment: @KugBuBu `Score` is the number you see to the left of a post, it's the amount of upvotes subtracted by the amount of downvotes.

Comment: @KugBuBu It's also useful to know that deleted posts are not in the data, so heavily downvoted (or upvoted) questions that are deleted will not influence the results.

Comment: You may add it to the answer. (Your last comment)

Answer (score 3):

You can run queries against the Stack Overflow data set on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries). Data there is up to a week old, as the database is refreshed every Sunday.

Comment: This query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204710/average-score-for-questions-and-answers-by-tag , seems like it was made to do what you want, however, it's taking to long to run. Try searching for other ones.